# After svn propset svn:ignore, files of svn repository are in M (edited) status

Tags: svn, svnignore

I wanted to ignore some files on my SVN.

I created a file: .svnignore in my root directory which contains:

```
*.sql
*.pyc
```

After doing:

```
svn propset svn:ignore -R -F .svnignore .
```

And doing:

```
svn st -u .
```

All my repository is in mode M (Edited). Why is that???

```
M            23630   core/templates/customers/index.html
 M           22740   core/templates/customers
 M           22740   core/templates/core/serial_number
 M           22740   core/templates/core
 M           22740   core/templates/orders
M            22742   core/templates/employees/index.html
M            22742   core/templates/employees/detail.html
 M           22740   core/templates/employees
 M           22740   core/templates/hours
 M           24365   core/templates/settings
 M           22740   core/templates/products
 M           22740   core/templates/projects
 M           22740   core/templates/tracker
```

Is it something to be worried about? Did I do this wrong?

Comment: repeat with `svn st -u -v` - you'll get answer (for *files*, for dirs it's correct as-is)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The command you've used seems OK. The svn documentation includes this statement for the `svn propset` command (see `svn help propset`):

> propset (pset, ps): Set the value of a property on files, dirs, or
>   revisions.

You should verify that you've not used other commands prior to the one you posted where you actually modified the files.

#### EDIT:

I ran a quick test on repo I have access to now to reproduce the same output you displayed, using `svn version 1.9.1 (r1698128)`, as follows:

```
$ svn propset svn:ignore "*.pyc" . -R
property 'svn:ignore' set on '.'
property 'svn:ignore' set on 'Backup'
property 'svn:ignore' set on 'Erp'
property 'svn:ignore' set on 'Import'
property 'svn:ignore' set on 'Launcher'
property 'svn:ignore' set on 'Overnight'
```

But the output did not list files (which is expected, but not what you got).

```
$ svn st -u
M          103990   Erp
M          103990   Launcher
M          103990   Overnight
M          103990   Backup
M          103990   Import
M          103990   .
```

Using the `svn st -u -v` suggested by the badger still shows the files unmodified, as the `svn:ignore` property is set on the directories. Quoting from the docs:

> Subversion recognizes the following special versioned properties on a 
>   directory:
>
> svn:ignore         - A list of file glob patterns to ignore, one per line.

Again, check that you've not used other commands or made other modifications that affect files.

If you feel you need to 'start over' to try again, you can revert the current changes in your working copy using the `svn revert -R .` command. Just make sure you're working with the properties only; you don't want to lose actual file content updates that have not yet been checked-in.

Comment: @LazyBadger: Quoting svn docs again for propset: "Changes a versioned **file** or directory property in a working copy." (emphasis added). The documentation is quite clear that *files* can be modified, not "directories only". There's no good reason for your down-vote.

Comment: `svn:ignore` is and always was **property of directory** "When found on a **versioned directory**, the `svn:ignore` property is expected to contain a list of newline-delimited file patterns that Subversion should use to determine ignorable objects in that *same* directory."

Comment: @LazyBadger: You're right, `svn:ignore` *specifically* is for directories, but not `propset` as a whole, which is what you indicated earlier. I've updated/re-worded my post. BTW, I did not find the specific sentence you've quoted is not in the svn help docs. What's your source?

Comment: [SVN Book](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.advanced.props.special.ignore.html) 5-th paragraph

Comment: Your test wasn't full. Ruben have modified *files*, because `-u` check **server-side updates** also (commits from another client, not received locally with `svn up`), and `-u -v` can show it clearly. For pure local-only modification `-u` have to be omitted

Comment: @LazyBadger: I mentioned did check with the `-u` and `-v` flags. I didn't post the output here because, aside from verbosity, it showed no difference for me on the status --the same dirs were marked as `M`. The files showed no changes.